# Does there exist a gem to parse human numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a helper [`#number_to_human`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human) to print large numbers, but is there an opposite helper to parse large numbers, similar to [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

[No specific search results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails+parse+million+commas+billion+thousands&ia=qa). [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is dead.

A bonus would be to accept a locale, to handle `,` and `.`.

I would like to parse things like

- $1m
- $15 million
- 999 thousand
- $999k
- $111 M
- 1,234,567.89
- €987.654,00
- $1.1 billion

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/cyzanfar/Academy-Award-Best-Picture-scraper/blob/master/lib/academy_award_best_picture_scraper.rb#L37
might help you solve your problem using regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something and customized it.

```
  def human_to_number(human)
    return human unless human.is_a? String
    return human if human.blank? # leave '' as is
    human.downcase!
    if human.index('k') || human.index('thousand')
      multiplier = 1000
    elsif human.index('m')
      multiplier = 1_000_000
    elsif human.index('b')
      multiplier = 1_000_000_000
    elsif human.index('t')
      multiplier = 1_000_000_000_000
    else
      multiplier = 1
    end
    number = human.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/,'').to_f
    number = number * multiplier
  end



irb(main):003:0> d.human_to_number '$1.2 million'
=> 1200000.0
irb(main):004:0> d.human_to_number '$1.2 billion'
=> 1200000000.0
irb(main):005:0> d.human_to_number '$1.2k'
=> 1200.0
irb(main):006:0> d.human_to_number '1.2k'
=> 1200.0
irb(main):007:0> d.human_to_number '555.66k'
=> 555660.0
```