# How do I create a filter in the model to parse text into integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The model has an integer field called `:size`. I use `#update model_params` in the controller. I know I could create a method in the controller to parse `size` from `params[:size]` before setting the value in the model, but I wanted to see if I could create a filter directly in the model instead. I tried

```
  validate :size_validation
  def size_validation
    size_number = human_to_number self.size
    if size_number < 1_000_000
      errors.add(:size, "has to be greater than USD $1 million")
    else
      self.size = size_number
    end
  end
  def human_to_number(human) ... end
```

But it didn't work and gave the error "undefined method 'downcase!' for 45:Fixnum". I then tried a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) instead.

```
  validates :size, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than: 1_000_000}
  before_update do      ###### also tried after_update
    self.size = human_to_number self.size
  end
```

But that gives a validation error 'Size is not a number'.

Comment: What is `human_to_number`? That seems to be a key detail of the question, and you've omitted it.

Comment: It's not relevant. It parses a string to a number.

Comment: `downcase` appears nowhere else in your code. Please include your error backtrace.

Comment: try parsing on a `before_validation :parse_size` filter

Comment: If [this previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658621/229044) is indeed the implementation of `human_to_number`, then it's *very* relevant. `size` is not always going to be a string that you can blindly parse. You need to account for the case where `size` is already an integer, such as an already persisted record loaded form the database.

Comment: @sa77 `before_validation` didn't help. It still converts to a number before it performs the validation.

Comment: @meagar OK that is a good point but it's not relevant to this question. It is converting to integer before it gets to my filter. It will _always_ be a string when submitted by the browser. Rails is converting the string to a number before it gets to my filter. How do I parse the value before Rails tries to parse it?

Comment: You want a custom setter, not a "filter' or a validation. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Duh! I was overcomplicating things! `def size=(s)
    s = human_to_number s
    super(s)
  end` only and `def human_to_number(human)
    return human unless human.is_a? String ...` to handle setting a value that's already an integer.